# Getting ORA Oracle error code using ODP.net?

Tags: vb.net, oracle

i use below DLL to connect direct to oracle from client.

```
oci.dll, Oracle.DataAccess.dll, oraociicus11.dll, OraOps11w.dll, orannzsbb11.dll, oraocci11.dll, ociw32.dll
```

connection string:

```
  Dim oradb As String = "Data Source=(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS_LIST=" _
+ "(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=172.20.128.33)(PORT=1521)))" _
+ "(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVER=DEDICATED)(SERVICE_NAME=bipcdb)));" _
+ "User Id=msavameri;Password=123456;"
```

but when I run application the following error occurs:

```
ORA-28547: connection to server failed, probable Oracle Net admin error
```

Comment: Are you able to log into your oracle environment from SQLplus on the machine you are using?

Comment: dont have sqlplus, but from **devart component** i success connect to oracle

Comment: The only thing I can think of is the connection string you have used in code is different to the connect details used in the Devart Component.  Anyway you can check?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a list of files needed by Oracle.DataAccess:

`oci.dll`

`Oracle.DataAccess.dll`

`orannzsbb11.dll`

`oraociei11.dll`

`OraOps11w.dll`

Be sure that all of these files are present in the client directory. It looks like the list you gave may be missing `oraociei11.dll`.